# Сохранить значение переменной в функции [jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#add_info').on('click', function() { // need to change other
        if($('#item_add_name').val() != '') { // fb
            table_visible(); items_num++;
            $('#head_tr_comp').append('<th class="new_new_th" id="tab_item' + items_num + '">' + $('#item_add_name').val() + '</th>');
            $('#rot_to_choose').append('<option>' + $('#item_add_name').val() + '</option>')
            $('#tab_item' + items_num).on('click', function() {
                $('#change_value').css({"opacity" : "1.0", "top" : "0%"}).focus();
                $('#change_value').on('focusout', function() {
                    $('#tab_item' + items_num).html($('#change_value').val());
                    $('#change_value').css({"opacity" : "0.0", "top" : "-2%"});
        });});}}
    });
```

В 8-ом лайне в качестве селектора используеться переменная, но позже в коде переменная приобретает другое значение. Мне нужно что бы можно было использовать прошлые версии переменной. Можно ли реализовать?

-Я тут перечитал и подумал что стоит привести пример:

При блюре(в коде) формы меняеться значение обьекта с переменной. В идеале надо что бы этот селектор был один раз определен, именно если мы нажимаем на этот обьект. Нужно что бы каждый раз когда переменная менялась этот лайн нет.

Comment: Что такой "лайн"? Сформулируйте конкретно, что вам нужно. И вообще зачем вам хранить прошлые значения переменной? и насколько прошлые? предыдущее или все прошлые значения? Возможно, стоит просто не менять переменную, а задавать новую. И тогда у вас будет доступно старое значение и новое, которое будет отдельно в новой переменной.

Comment: Строка кода (номер строки кода). У меня в пред-последней строке висит изменение значения обьекта селектор которого береться из переменной. К примеру var items_num = 1. Получиться $('#tab_item1').html($('#change_value').val()). Потом переменная получает новое значение(items_num++). Нужно что бы в   $('#tab_item' + items_num).html($('#change_value').val()) так и оставалось на месте переменной число один. У меня стоит кнопка для добавления обьектов в таблицу. Готовить переменные очень не удобно, удобнее использовать одну.

Comment: то есть там всегда должно быть значение равное "1"?

Comment: В этой строке кода в переменной  items_num всегда должно быть значение один. Независимо от того, изменилось ли значение в переменной.

Comment: создайте тогда просто еще одну переменную со значением один до 
того, как измените что-то. И все. Обращайтесь к ней в последующем коде.

Comment: Я уже говорил - у меня стоит добавление обьектов в таблицу, для каждего нужен контролируемый айди. Примерный код : https://jsfiddle.net/swsLyxx4/3/